Harry Potter Time Travel fic on Wattpad where Harry and Hermione travel back in time after losing the war
I read this fic a while ago and for the life of me I can’t find it again on Wattpad. I will admit my memory is hazy but I’ll include everything I can remember about it.
It starts with Harry and Hermione losing the war and poisoning themselves/unaliving themselves after confessing their love for each other. I don’t remember if it was on purpose or not but they travel back in time to either when they were born or when they’re around the age of 11.
Sorry I can’t be more precise on that. I do know they remember each other and somehow find each other. I know he becomes an animagus, I believe a bird of some sort but I’m not certain. The biggest thing I remember is they use the muggle military to help fight the death eater. Using coordinated drone/bomb strikes to take out death eater homes and such, and I believe it also says something about Hermione being from a magical family though her parents are non magical. Her grandfather or great grandfather was a wizard or knew of their lineage. Please don’t quote me on the last part, it’s been a few years since I read it and I’ve read hundreds of fix’s since then so some of that might have mixed in. The military part is true though, I remember that part from it and I really hope it will be enough to find it.

It's not a perfect match, but The Time-Meddlers is very close.
The war is going badly - Hagrid is killed early in the story - so Harry and Hermione take a potion to send them back in time. The potion kills them as part of the process, and indeed they pass through the same sort of waiting room that Harry did in Deathly Hallows and they meet (the dead) Dumbledore there.
They go back to when Harry first went to Hogwarts, so he would have been about eleven, and Harry does become an Animagus.
The main difference is that I don't think they use drones to attack the houses of Death Eaters (I can't be sure as I only skimmed the book) though they do use Muggle bomb in the final battle.

I read this recently. I think it's 'In This World and the Next' by RobSt on fanfiction.net.They didn't kill themselves, but were sentenced to death by Dementor by the Wizengamot. They end up back on the train to Hogwarts at the age of 11. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjf-oKS8MaHAxUNbEEAHX1oCEkQFnoECB8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.fanfiction.net%2Fs%2F5627314%2F1%2FIn-this-World-and-the-Next&usg=AOvVaw1xPfZs9BLXB7Ib3XYoO6rB&opi=89978449
